# Parse GeoJSON polygons with holes library

Tags: polygon, geojson, java

We're trying to use polygons taken from OpenStreetMap and determine user locations.
We're using `geojson` to parse the GeoJSONs we generate from OSM, but the deserialized polygons aren't being populated correctly - no holes are detected, instead we get a set of polygons.

Examining the the exported GeoJSON from OSM does seem to represent a set of multi-polygons and not a polygon with holes.
ie, [Rome (OSM)](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/41485#map=11/41.8666/12.5876),
Vatican isn't being populated as a hole, instead there are two polygons - the Rome polygon(containing the Vatican), and the Vatican polygon.

Checking some tools such as *Mapbox* or *JOSM* do parse it correct and display the holes.

Is there a `java` lib that parses polygons with holes even on such cases?

[Rome's GeoJSON (OSM)](http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/get_geojson.py?id=41485&params=0)

**Snippet (Kotlin):**

```
val romeGeom = GeometryJSON().readGeometryCollection(getFileContent("rome.json")).getGeometryN(0)
    with (org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory()) {
        val map = mapOf(
            "rome" to createPoint(org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate(12.4458, 41.9040)),
            "vatican" to createPoint(org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate(12.44597, 41.90197)), // Expected to be false
            "rome2" to createPoint(org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate(12.3049, 42.1121)))

        map.forEach { (key, value) ->
            println("$key: ${value.within(romeGeom)}")
        }
    }
```

Using *gt-geojsondatastore v26.3* yields `StackOverflowError` (tried couple of geo-jsons):

```
val store = GeoJSONDataStore(getFileUrl("rome.json"))
val featureSource = store.getFeatureSource(store.typeNames[0])
val feat = featureSource.features //StackOverflowError
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:860)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:82)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1068)
at org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONReader.isConnected(GeoJSONReader.java:124)
at org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONReader.getIterator(GeoJSONReader.java:406)
at org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONFeatureSource.buildFeatureType(GeoJSONFeatureSource.java:107)
at org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONFeatureStore.buildFeatureType(GeoJSONFeatureStore.java:78)
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getAbsoluteSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:338)
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:307)
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getSchema(ContentDataStore.java:295)
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getSchema(ContentDataStore.java:633)
at org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONDataStore.getSchema(GeoJSONDataStore.java:111)
at org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONFeatureSource.buildFeatureType(GeoJSONFeatureSource.java:121)
at org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONFeatureStore.buildFeatureType(GeoJSONFeatureStore.java:78)
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getAbsoluteSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:338)
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:307)
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getSchema(ContentDataStore.java:295)
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getSchema(ContentDataStore.java:633)
at org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONDataStore.getSchema(GeoJSONDataStore.java:111)
at org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONFeatureSource.buildFeatureType(GeoJSONFeatureSource.java:121)
at org.geotools.data.geojson.GeoJSONFeatureStore.buildFeatureType(GeoJSONFeatureStore.java:78)
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getAbsoluteSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:338)
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:307)
```

Comment: [softwarerecs.se] is the SE place for software recommendations.

Comment: have you tried GeoTools (http://geotools.org)

Comment: @IanTurton Yes I have. Actually the `geojson` is by _geotools_

Comment: Can you add the code you are running? I'm not clear on what exactly the issue is

Comment: @IanTurton Snippet added.

Comment: The geojson module is deprecated and abandoned, so try using the geojson datastore

Comment: 10x @IanTurton, but using this lib yields `StackOverflowError`. Answer updated with snippet.

Comment: Would need to see the stack trace to say what is up,

Comment: Obviously.. @IanTurton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at this a few weeks ago on a separate platform:

Here is what I said:

---

Well, it looks like the multipolygons are incorrectly generated. From the [spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-3.1.6),

> A linear ring MUST follow the right-hand rule with respect to the
> area it bounds, i.e., exterior rings are counterclockwise, and
> holes are clockwise

Check the exterior ring for Rome. Technically speaking, it is the “inner” ring with another “inner” ring from the Vatican.

---

For a compliant geojson where software doesn't have to guess, I would use Nominatim. An earlier version of the specification *did not* specify that winding rule, but software may not want to "guess" what the appropriate behavior is.

Example:
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/Rome?format=geojson&polygon_geojson=1

See https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Overview/ for the full API.
See https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/ for the usage policy

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to parse a `GeometryCollection` not a `FeatureCollection`. What you have is not [GeoJSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-1.5) but just JSON. There is a class `com.bedatadriven.jackson.datatype.jts.parsers.GeometryParser` which is packaged in with GeoTools that should handle this sort of file:

```
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;

import com.bedatadriven.jackson.datatype.jts.JtsModule;
import com.bedatadriven.jackson.datatype.jts.parsers.GenericGeometryParser;
import com.bedatadriven.jackson.datatype.jts.parsers.GeometryParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

public class ReadJSONGeometryCollection {
  private static JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
    File f = new File("/home/ian/Downloads/rome.geojson");
    GenericGeometryParser parser = new GenericGeometryParser(gf);
    try (JsonParser lParser = factory.createParser(new FileInputStream(f))) {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      mapper.registerModule(new JtsModule());
      ObjectNode node = mapper.readTree(lParser);
      GeometryParser<Geometry> gParser = new GenericGeometryParser(gf);
      Geometry g = gParser.geometryFromJson(node);
      System.out.println(g);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("problem parsing Geometry", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Which gives me the following output from your file:

```
 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (MULTIPOLYGON (((12.2429442 42.0172481, 12.242935 42.0171496, 12.2429089 ... 12.4457442 41.9019597))))
```

Which explains why you aren't seeing any holes, there aren't any - it is one big `MultiPolygon` (inside a `GeometryCollection`). There should be no problem parsing a geometry with holes in it, the code is all there.

Comment: You say that the (geo)json doesn't contain holes, but it clearly does at OSM.
Is there a way to calc those holes? I tried with `within`, `covers` etc but none gave me the expected results - `f(a)=true, f(b)=false`.

Comment: Somehow when exporting it you have collapsed it into a single multipolygon with no holes - no idea how to fix it